# Can't pickle local object when multiprocessing with pool.map

Tags: python, multithreading, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use `multiprocessing` with the python `Pool` function, using `functools.partial` to input several arguments with constant value into the `pool.map` command (i.e the first argument is the only varying).

The issue is that when I run the code I get the following error and I don't know how why or how to solve it:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 
    'get_MAX_SNR_for_eventdata_file.<locals>.get_SNR_multiprocess'
```

I don't know why it cannot pickle an object. This is the code (which is inside a top-level function):

```
def get_SNR_multiprocess(binning, event_data, energy_interval, tstart, tstop, trigger_time):
    """ This function just changes the order of arguments to be able to use partial"""
    SNR=get_max_SNR_est(event_data, energy_interval, binning, tstart, tstop, trigger_time)
    return SNR

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

for i in range(len(energybands)-1):
    energy_interval=[energybands[i],energybands[i+1]]
    partial_func=partial(get_SNR_multiprocess, event_data=event_data, 
                         energy_interval=energy_interval, tstart=tstart, tstop=tstop, 
                         trigger_time=trigger_time)
    SNRlist=pool.map(partial_func,timescales)
pool.close()
```

I get a hint that the problem might have to do with the fact that only functions defined at top-level of a module can be pickled, according to [What can be pickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). However, I cannot figure out exactly the problem in my code, or how to solve it.

The function `get_max_SNR_est` in the code is a function defined in the same script and returns a value. This function is dependant on other function of the same script (which depends on another and so on...).

Just FYI, the code works without multiprocessing using a for loop, like:

```
SNRlist=[]
for i in range(len(energybands)-1):
    energy_interval=[energybands[i],energybands[i+1]]
    for binning in timescales:
        SNR=get_max_SNR_est(event_data, energy_interval, binning, tstart, tstop, 
                            trigger_time)
        SNRlist.append(SNR)
```

**Edit**: I forgot to put that the code that I am showing here is already in a function. Based on @martineau's comment I took the function `get_SNR_multiprocessing` out of the aforementioned function, which solves the issue of pickling (see answer).

Comment: The problem is because internally `partial()` creates a [`partial` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) which obviously doesn't happen at the top-level of a module. The reason the error message says `get_SNR_multiprocess` instead of `partial_func` is because that's the name `partial` gave to this object (i.e. it's "wrapping" the original function). I'm not sure how to fix the problem for a variable number of `partial` objects.

Comment: @martineau your comment helped me solve an issue, by taking the `get_SNR_multiprocess` out of the main function (which I didn't mention before, but now it's added to the post). Now, another issue appears

Comment: I think should delete this question and ask a new one explaining just your new problem — since the pickling issue has been solved (you're welcome).

Comment: Done. I haven't posted the other question elsewhere because I found a solution. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @martineau's comment I found a solution for this issue. As I mentioned later in the *edit* of the questions, the code that I am showing here is already in a function. I took the function `get_SNR_multiprocessing` out of the aforementioned function, which solves the issue of pickling. The new code (where I am showing the function that contained the code shown above) looks like this:

```
def get_SNR_multiprocess(binning, event_data, energy_interval, tstart, tstop, trigger_time):
    """ This function just changes the order of arguments to be able to use functools.partial for multiprocessing"""
    SNR=get_max_SNR_est(event_data, energy_interval, binning, tstart, tstop, trigger_time)
    return SNR

def get_MAX_SNR_for_eventdata_file(event_data, energybands, timescales, tstart, tstop, trigger_time):
    """
    Gives the maximum SNR of all timescales and energybands given for a given event_data file
    """ 
    SNRlist=[]
    for i in range(len(energybands)-1):
        energy_interval=[energybands[i],energybands[i+1]]

        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            partial_func=partial(get_SNR_multiprocess, event_data=event_data, energy_interval=energy_interval, tstart=tstart, tstop=tstop, trigger_time=trigger_time)
            SNRlist=pool.map(partial_func,timescales)
```

Unfortunately, this method takes the same time as the original method with a `for` loop.

Comment: Unfortunately multiprocessing often won't speed things up if a lot of data has to be exchanged between the processes due to the overhead. ***However*** in Python 3.8 they added a [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) class which removes a lot of the overhead (namely the use pickled data and the associated pickling and unpickling of it) — so you might want to try it out.